# How to send get parameters as pretty URL on search form in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, pretty-urls

I have search form to list properties/ads through certain criteria (city, price, quadrature, property type). I am trying to get pretty url like this for example

```
project/search/city/London/price/1_10000/quadrature/1_150/propertyType/flat
```

instead of this like it is now

```
project/filter?_token=mCwLL58vOxGHtxEBmntPPcks7nV9n3DHXCNKt7hE&city=London&min_price=1&max_price=10000&min_quadrature=1&max_quadrature=150&propertyType=flat&submit=
```

It is my first time to do something like this, and I am relatively new in Laravel. I tried with javascript's onsubmit function to rewrite the URL but that didn't work, also I googled and tried to create a method for form action then read the query strings and redirect to one with pretty url but I failed. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is some of my code, but it doesn't work obviously:

web.php

```
Route::get('/search', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/filter', 'CategoryController@filter');
```

CategoryController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
public function index()
    {
    $data = \DB::table('properties');
    return view('categories.search', compact('data'));
    }

    public function filter(Request $request)
    {
        $data = \DB::table('properties');

        if ($request->city) {
        $data = $data->where('city', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->city . "%");
        }

        if ($request->min_price && $request->max_price ) {
            $data = $data->where('price', '>=', $request->min_price)
                     ->where('price', '<=', $request->max_price);
        }

        if ($request->min_quadrature && $request->max_quadrature ) {
            $data = $data->where('quadrature', '>=', $request->min_quadrature)
                     ->where('quadrature', '<=', $request->max_quadrature);
        }

        $data = $data->paginate(10);

        return view('categories.search', compact('data'));
    }

}
```

search.blade.php

```
<form id="form" action="/filter" method="GET">
    @csrf

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
          <label>City</label>
          <input name="city" list="result" id="input" class="form-control">
          <datalist id="result"></datalist>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
          <label>Price</label>
          <input type="number" name="min_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Min Price">
          <input type="number" name="max_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
          <label>Quadrature</label>
          <input type="number" name="min_quadrature" class="form-control" placeholder="Min quadrature">
          <input type="number" name="max_quadrature" class="form-control" placeholder="Max quadrature">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-6">
          <h5>Property type</h4>
            <div class="d-block my-3 ">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="house" name="propertyType" value="house" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="house">House</label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="flat" name="propertyType" value="flat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="flat">Flat</label>
              </div>
      </div>

    <hr class="mb-4">

    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" onsubmit="window.location.href=this.action + '/' + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['city'].value) + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['min_price'].value) + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['max_price'].value) + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['min_quadrature'].value) + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['max_quadrature'].value) + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['propertyType'].value) + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['propertyBidAsk'].value) + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['propertyPayment'].value); return false;">Search</button>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using Laravel's [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters):

web.php:

```php
Route::get('/search/city/{city}/price/{price}/quadrature/{quadrature}/propertyType/{propertyType}', 'CategoryController@index');
```

CategoryController.php:

```php
public function index($city, $price, $quadrature, $propertyType)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I did that, it is useful info, but I still get the same url, and now page 404 not found. apparently something in my controller is bad. Can you help?

Comment: The problem is not with your controller, but with the way the forms do work. They will **always** send **GET** parameters as a part of the **query string** and not the URL itself. To get the result you want - you need to collect form data using javascript and build the url you want. Why not use the standart **?var=foo** query string way?

Comment: @Marko, if you are trying to create a filter, then you need to use middlewares to form your URL as you want.

Comment: @Thepeanut this assignment I'm working requires that I build it that way. do you have some link as help on how to do that using javascript?

Comment: @AndrewG. Can you explain how to?

Comment: That is not an easy task. Personally I combined the query string parts and attached to the requested URL. In your code you need to remove that form and create a separate helper function to attach single query string to the request. That will give you much more flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

You can make without javascript...

Html Form:

```html
    <form id="form" action="{{ route('filter') }}" method="GET">
     ... <!-- Your html -->
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" >Search</button>
```

Route file:

```php
    <?php
    // ... Your Routes
    Route::get('/filter', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
      // Redirect to named route
      return redirect()->route('search', ['city' => $request['city'], 'price' => $request['price'], 'quadrature' => $request['quadrature'], 'propertyType' => $request['propertyType']]);    
    })->name('filter');
    Route::get('/search/city/{city}/price/{price}/quadrature/{quadrature}/propertyType/{propertyType}', 'CategoryController@filter')->name('search');
```

Controller file:

```php
    <?php
    // ... Your Class namespace and libraries
    class CategoryController extends Controller
    {
      public function filter(Request $request)
      {
        dd( $request );
        // ... Your code
      }
    }
```